# Follow a javascript link with mechanize and python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm doing some web scraping and the project is almost done, except for I need to click a javascript link and I can't work out how to with Python and mechanize.

On one of the pages, a list of javascript links appear and I want to follow them in turn, scrape some data, and repeat. I know mechanize doesn't work with javascript but does anyone know a workaround? Here's the code I use to isolate the links:

```
for Auth in iterAuths:
     Auth = str(Auth.contents[0]).strip()
     br.find_link(text=Auth)
```

now if I do `br.follow_link(text=Auth)`, I get an error `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: javascript>`.

If I do `print br.click_link(text=Auth')`, it prints as `Request for javascript:SendThePage('5660')`

I just need to get through the javascript link. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I needed to do something similar, I looked at the links I was trying to follow.

Some of them were static links generated with javascript. They were predictable/consistent enough that I could manually generate a list before hand.

Others were just constructed URLs with parameters. These too could be analyzed before hand and generated python-side and passed as a request instead of a "click on this link."

If you need to actually execute the javascript, you could run a PyV8 + Mechanize hybrid. I've been playing with this a bit and it seems pretty cool. PyV8 bridges Python with the V8 Javascript engine allowing you to create JS environments and execute arbitrary code. It does a great job going back and forth between the two languages.

I don't have any sample code, but one of these 3 solutions will work for you :) Good luck!

Comment: Do you have any resources on installing PyV8, I'm having some trouble.

Comment: @ConstantlyConfused at this point, I'd just consider using Selenium with a PhantomJS backend so you can run it headless. That workflow has come so far, and mechanize is pretty dead.